# Refresh pug variable value every x seconds

Tags: node.js, pug, setinterval

is it possible to refresh a pug variable every x seconds?
I have the following code:

```js
router.get("/rooms", function(req, res) {
  device_data.find({
    "selector": {
      "payload.d.data": {
        "$gte": 0
      }
    },
    "fields": [
      "_id",
      "deviceId",
      "payload.d.data",
      "payload.d.time"
    ],
    "sort": [{
      "payload.d.time": "desc"
    }]
  }, function(err, device) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      res.render(path + 'rooms', {
        rooms: rooms,
      });
});
```

I tryed to use setInterval before device_data.find but it don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid this is not possible. Pug is a markup language that compiles down to static HTML. Because of this limitation, it can't dynamically update - once it's compiled to HTML, Pug has no say anymore in what happens to the page. If you want the page to update dynamically, that has to happen on initiative of the frontend side (i.e. from within the browser). For example, you could put that setInterval call in a client JS script which you link into the HTML page, and let it periodically fetch a page with the counter as a parameter (or use AJAX to do some similar fetching procedure).